# 3D caffe make runtest error

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

make 3D-caffe, make all and make test is fine. But make runtest is wrong here
it looks like a relation with GPU setting, but I am not sure

```
 [----------] 4 tests from SoftmaxWithLossLayerTest/3, where TypeParam
= caffe::GPUDevice<double> [ RUN      ]     SoftmaxWithLossLayerTest/3.TestGradient
*** Aborted at 1493416676 (unix time) try "date -d @1493416676" if you  are using GNU date *** PC: @     0x7f4ddfd59a05 caffe::Blob<>::gpu_data()
*** SIGSEGV (@0x17ec) received by PID 15580 (TID 0x7f4de5f8fac0) from PID 6124; stack trace: ***
@     0x7f4ddf3a1390 (unknown)
@     0x7f4ddfd59a05 caffe::Blob<>::gpu_data()
@     0x7f4ddfd93ad0 caffe::SoftmaxWithLossLayer<>::Forward_gpu()
@           0x45ba59 caffe::Layer<>::Forward()
@           0x4844a0 caffe::GradientChecker<>::CheckGradientSingle()
@           0x487603 caffe::GradientChecker<>::CheckGradientExhaustive()
@           0x5d44c7 caffe::SoftmaxWithLossLayerTest_TestGradient_Test<>::TestBody()
@           0x8ac7d3 testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
@           0x8a5dea testing::Test::Run()
@           0x8a5f38 testing::TestInfo::Run()
@           0x8a6015 testing::TestCase::Run()
@           0x8a72ef testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests()
@           0x8a7613 testing::UnitTest::Run()
@           0x4512a9 main
@     0x7f4ddefe7830 __libc_start_main
@           0x4577c9 _start
@                0x0 (unknown) Makefile:468: recipe for target 'runtest' failed make: *** [runtest] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: thank you, I mean that I down load 3D caffe code to make, but when I do "make runtest", something is wrong just like I have posted code,thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would love to help you, but your message is unclear.  I would suggest checking your grammar and word choice next time.

Comment: please don't post comment as answer. As you earn points you will be able to comment. Before that please refrain.